# C++ (sort of) factory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, factory

I've seen a number of posts regarding C++ factories, but so far I haven't seen a solution that solves my problem. (Though I may be missing something.)

Example console app:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ResourceManager;

/// abstract base class
class Identity
{
public:
    int Id() const { return _id; }

    /// make this an abstract class
    virtual ~Identity() = 0 {}

protected:
    Identity() { _id = _nextId++; }

private:
    int _id;
    static int _nextId;
};

int Identity::_nextId = int();

/// derived classes
class Component : public Identity
{
    friend class ResourceManager;
public:
    ~Component() { }
};

class Entity : public Identity
{
    friend class ResourceManager;
public:
    ~Entity() { }
};


class ResourceManager
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    T& Create()
    {
        auto ptr = std::make_shared<T>();
        auto id = ptr->Id();

        _resources[id] = std::move(ptr);
        return *dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(_resources[id]);
    }

private:
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Identity>> _resources;
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Factory test" << endl;

    ResourceManager r;

    auto& e = r.Create<Entity>();
    cout << "e.id = " << e.Id() << endl;

    Entity e2;
    cout << "e2.id = " << e2.Id() << endl;

    Component c;
    cout << "c.id = " << c.Id() << endl;

    std::getchar();
}
```

I need to make sure that only `ResourceManager` can instantiate `Entity,` `Component` and any classes that derive from them.

I've looked and adding `ResourceManager` as a friend class to `Identity,` and making the constructors private or protected, with no success. (This could be a blind alley, or just an implementation problem on my end.)

Any suggestions?

**Update and Edit**

Replaced code with compilable example. Although the constructor for `Identity()` is protected, I can still directly instantiate derived classes.

Comment: What does "no success" exactly mean? compile error? runtime error? nasal demons?

Comment: Friendship is not inherited.

Comment: `static int _nextId = int();` looks suspicious for a start.

Comment: @marko - yeah, I wrote that in Notepad++. I need `_id` to be unique for each instance of `Identity` or derived classes that get instantiated.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'll add that to my example and post the errors.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The issue is that I'm *not* getting errors. Despite jumping through `friend`/`protected` hoops, I can still instantiate the derived classes directly. I'm hoping I don't have to declare a `protected` ctor in *every* derived class, but that seems likely. Hmmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

`friend class ResourceManager;` should be in each derivated classes.
(friend is not inherited).

```
class ResourceManager;

/// abstract base class
class Identity
{
public:
    int Id() const { return _id; }

    /// make this an abstract class
    virtual ~Identity() = 0;

    // Forbid any copy
    Identity(const Identity&) = delete;
    Identity(const Identity&&) = delete;
    Identity& operator = (const Identity&) = delete;
    Identity& operator = (Identity&&) = delete;

protected:
    Identity() { _id = _nextId++; }

private:
    int _id;
    static int _nextId;
};

// empty destructor
Identity::~Identity() {}

int Identity::_nextId = 0;

/// derived classes
class Component : public Identity
{
    friend class ResourceManager;
public:
    ~Component() { }
protected:
    Component() = default;
};

class Entity : public Identity
{
    friend class ResourceManager;
public:
    ~Entity() { }
protected:
    Entity() = default;
};


class ResourceManager
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    T& Create()
    {
         std::unique_ptr<T> ptr(new T);
         T& res = *ptr;

        _resources[ptr->Id()] = std::move(ptr);
        return res;
    }

    /// TODO: need to make sure that resource ID is actually of type T
    /// and that _resources contains ID.

    template<typename T>
    T* Get(int id)
    {
        auto it = _resources.find(id);
        if (it == _resources.end()) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(it->second.get());
    }

private:
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Identity>> _resources;
};
```

Note that since `ResourceManager` owns the resource I change `std::shared_ptr` to `std::unique_ptr`.
I fixed `ResourceManager::Get` with invalid id.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Unfortunately, this has a few problems: Without declaring an implementation for `~Identity`, I get an unresolved external when building. If I add that, I can then directly instantiate `Entity` and `Component` with `auto& e = Entity()`. Suggestions?

Comment: @DavidLively: Fixed. You may implement `~Identity` and still let declare it virtual pure.

Comment: Of course, it'd be nice if VS2012 supported `delete` and `default`. But, for the most part this works. Only issue is that, in `ResourceManager::Create`, `*ptr` isn't valid after it's been `move()`d. Instead, I copy the ID from `ptr->Id()`, move T into the map, then return the reference from the map.

Comment: Fixed the move issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a protected construtor?

```
class Identity
{
     friend class ResourceManager;

public:
     int Id() { return _id; } 

     virtual ~Identity() = 0;

protected:
    Identity() {
         _id = _nextId++;        
    }

private:
    static int _nextId;
    // do not forget to put "int Identity::_nextId = 0;" in a source file
};

Identity::~Identity()
{
}
```

But you need to repeat this pattern in every derived class. Thus making `ResourceManager` a friend and making the constructor `private` or `protected`.

Comment: Great answer. I accepted Jarod's because of the fairly complete implementation.